# Utilizar uma classe sql.Connection para cada tarefa ou apenas uma referenciada globalmente?

Tags: java, sql, conexão

Tenho uma classe que é responsável por verificar a conta e a senha do usuário ao efetuar o login e, futuramente, terei de implementar uma outra classe para obter outros dados no banco e criar uma nova conexão.

Seria uma boa opção utilizar apenas uma classe `sql.Connection` no quesito performance e legibilidade do código? Poderia acarretar em problemas futuros?

Comment: Olá, Iago. Isto é algum projeto acadêmico simples ou uma aplicação real? Em aplicações profissionais, o gerenciamento de conexões geralmente é delegado a um container web ou a um framework. Se for um programa feito para aprender, uma forma simples é ter uma classe que retorna novas conexões para as outras. Se puder dar mais detalhes, será mais fácil ajudar. Abraço!

Comment: Olá. É tanto pra aprendizado quanto pra uma aplicação real @utluiz. A aplicação no caso é para android, comunicação celular para sql server e vice-versa.

Comment: Ao menos deveriam comentar a razão do meu tópico ser fechado, sem retorno não posso fazer nada.

Comment: Não votei para fechar, mas acredito que o motivo é que os detalhes da pergunta estão espalhados pelos comentários e a pergunta em si está ampla, falta a tag sobre ser para o Android, pois assim dá a impressão de que pode ser para qualquer programa Java. Se você quer que a pergunta seja reaberta, edite e adicione lá as informações que foram completadas nos comentários. No SO, a pergunta deve conter todos os detalhes necessários.

Comment: Eu não respondi sua pergunta porque não trabalho com Android, mas relendo agora, queria acrescentar uma coisa: manter uma conexão aberta não é recomendado simplesmente porque você vai estar consumindo recursos sem necessidade a maior parte do tempo. Além disso, o app pode sair e voltar à memória a qualquer momento, então dependendo de onde guardar o objeto ele pode se tornar "stale" e em algum momento se tornar inutilizável.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá, jovem!

O recomendado é que você crie uma Factory de conexões ao banco, uma DAO(Data access object) para manipular o acesso e aquisição das informações ao banco e, por fim, uma que permita você validar se as informações são válidas ou não.

Dessa forma você conseguirá manter uma alta coesão um baixo acoplamento.

Veja, na camada mais alta, que chamarei de Validator, você recebe o seu objeto com as propriedades do usuário, como login e senha. 
Neste validator você solicita as informações pro banco através da DAO - que eu recomendaria que fosse injetada - e então homologa se os valores estão coerentes ou não.
Na DAO você verifica qual banco você deve acessar, e então chama sua factory. Isso pode ser lendo alguma propriedade do sistema, lendo algum arquivo externo, ou mesmo só solicitando à uma outra classe.

Seguindo essa ideia, se vc tiver qualquer problema na validação, você só altera no Validator; se tiver problemas na consulta, altera na DAO; por fim, se for algum problema na criação da conexão, altera na factory.

Quaisquer dúvidas, é só falar!

Saudações

**Editado**

Aqui é possivel encontrar um exemplo:
[Exemplo](https://github.com/jeancopp/design-patterns-examples/tree/master/arquitetura-example)

Comment: Me corrija se estiver errado para ver se entendi, cria uma classe FactoryConnection, que sempre me entrega uma conexão quando eu preciso, outra classe, no caso a DAO, que ira utilizar dessa conexão e fazer a transferência dos dados necessários, e uma para validar informações, certo?

Comment: Exatamente isso, @IagoCoutinhoCampos!
Vou tentar fazer um exemplo e te passo.
A ideia é separa as responsabilidades. 
Na dao, vc manipula acesso a banco e as pesquisas, por exemplo. Na validator, vc checa se aquela informação faz sentido. Por fim, mas não menos importante, na factory vc cria a sua conexão com o banco.

Comment: Isso não geraria muitas instâncias que seriam usadas e logo em seguida descartadas acarretando em muito lixo na memória?

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui, @IagoCoutinhoCampos. https://github.com/jeancopp/design-patterns-examples/tree/master/arquitetura-example

Quanto a essa preocupação, basta que o java esteja bem configurado para executar a limpeza. O consumo de memória tende a ficar serrilhado, e de tempos em tempos limpará. 

Se você usar injeção de dependências, você já elimina isso, pois as implementações do CDI vão controlar isso pra vc. O spring, por exemplo, vc pode criar como singleton, então uma instância é compartilhada pela aplicação como um todo.

Comment: Particularmente meus DAOs recebem uma fábrica de conexões e tenho somente uma instância de cada classe DAO. E lançam algo do tipo `DataAccessException` em vez de `SQLException`, levando em conta que a camada que faz uso dos DAOs não deve saber detalhes de implementação da camada inferior (isto é, que os dados vêm de um banco SQL).